# How to use Invoke() if the invoked method takes in a variable number of parameters

Tags: java, reflection, invoke, illegalargumentexception

I'm just starting to learn reflection and to do so I have a little Math app.
The program wraps a logic class, and at runtime looks through the logic class it wraps for methods (in this case, add, subtract, multiply, and divide). The methods look like the one below.

```
public int add(int... args){
   int result = 0;
   for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++){
        result+=args[i];
   }
   return  result;
}
```

As you can see, this method (all the other ones do as well) takes in int... args, so I can pass in any number of ints to add together.

I then attempt to solve the Math question like so

```
int[] params = new int[numinputs];
//populate params with what numbers the user types in.
int result = (Integer) methodToCall.invoke(logicInstance, params);
```

If i call it this way, I get an IllegalArguementException on invoke().

So I guess the tl:dr is :

How do I call invoke() if the method being invoked takes in a params instead of a hardcoded number of parameters.

Thanks :)

Comment: `varargs` compiles to bytecode where the method has one argument: an array of integers. The compiler is just nice enough to replace all variable-argument calls to the method with an implicit array creation. So, you should find the method by the one that takes a single _array_ of integers

Comment: If methodToCall actually points to the right method, your code should run fine. What do you get if you try `System.out.println(methodToCall.toString());`?

Comment: @jarnbjo No, if `methodToCall` points to the right method, he should be doing: `methodToCall.invoke(logicInstance, new Object[] { params });` The second parameter to `invoke` is an array of objects, one for each parameter. At runtime, you can't pass a variable number of arguments to the method. You must pass what the bytecode expects, which is an array of integers as _the first parameter_.

Comment: @Colin: Yes. Since Method#invoke is itself a varargs method (the signature is `Object obj, Object ... args`), `m.invoke(obj, params)` and `m.invoke(obj, new Object[] {params})` is equivalent, unless the type of params is or can be cast to Object[], which is not the case here.

Comment: @jarnbjo Yes, but varargs methods are not as convenient when one of the parameters you want to pass is, itself, an array. In this particular case, you're right that it _should_ work, but only because he's using a primitive `int[]` array. If, instead, he were using `Integer` (or _anything_ which extends `Object`), he would need to explicitly wrap the varargs call in a `new Object[] { }` since anything else (such as `Integer[]`) could be cast to `Object[]` and would not be definitive. Personally, I would be explicit in this case.

Comment: @Colin: Why do you think that the compiler only *should* follow the language specification? For all reasonable purposes, I have no doubt that it *will* and *must* follow the JLS and in this case, the code works as expected if `methodToCall` points to the right method.

Comment: @jarnbjo Emphasis was on _should_ not because I don't believe that the compiler would follow the specification, but rather because I think it's a relatively poor practice to encourage. Given that one method works _only_ on primitives and the other works for all types, I personally think it best to encourage the strategy that works in all cases. However, this doesn't answer the question and I understand your perspective - but we don't need to continue this discussion further I don't believe.

Answer (score 0):

try to cast to Object params

```
    int[] params = new int[5]

    Class<?> c = Class.forName("your class");
    Object t = c.newInstance();
    Method m = c.getMethod("add", int[].class);
    //populate params with what numbers the user types in.
    int result = (Integer) m.invoke(t,(Object) params);
```